# Combine blocks of different images and produce a new image

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I have six photographs. I changed them into block structure. Consider an image of size 200x200.
1. I converted into blocks of 10x10 so now I have 400 blocks in total each of size 10x10. I did this for each image.
2. Then I found the mean value for each block. Again for all images.
3. Found the maximum of mean values of all blocks. So now I have a array of length 400 where each value is the maximum of block values.
4. Also found the indices of these maximum value(blocks number and the image number)

Now using this image and block number I want to produce an image such that it should pick blocks from original images and put them into empty images to make the final image.
One approach I thought was to pick blocks by row and match it against the original image. Then place that block in the empty image so that same block is placed in the empty image as the original image. This could be wrong but just an idea I had but still I don't know how to proceed with this.

```
img = [cv2.imread(file,0) for file in glob.glob("resized/*.jpg")]
X=[]
for im in img:
    arr = np.asarray(im)
    arr = np.split(arr, 20)
    arr = np.array([np.split(x, 20, 1) for x in arr])
    mat = [arr[i][j].mean() for i in range(20) for j in range(20)]
    X.append(mat)
max_X = list(zip(*X))
result = [max(i) for i in max_X]
print(result)
image_number = np.argmax(X,axis=0)
print(image_number)
result1 = [(row.index(max(row)),index) for index, row in enumerate(max_X)]
print(result1)
```

```
[(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (0, 4), (0, 5), (0, 6), (0, 7), (0, 8), (0, 9), (0, 10), (0, 11), (0, 12), (0, 13), (0, 14), (0, 15), (0, 16), (0, 17), (0, 18), (0, 19), (0, 20), (0, 21), (0, 22), (0, 23), (0, 24), (0, 25), (0, 26), (0, 27), (0, 28), (0, 29), (0, 30), (0, 31), (0, 32), (0, 33), (0, 34), (0, 35), (0, 36), (0, 37), (0, 38), (0, 39), (0, 40), (0, 41), (0, 42), (0, 43), (0, 44), (0, 45), (1, 46), (2, 47), (0, 48), (0, 49), (0, 50), (0, 51), (0, 52), (0, 53), (0, 54), (0, 55), (0, 56), (0, 57), (0, 58), (0, 59), (0, 60), (0, 61), (0, 62), (0, 63), (1, 64), (0, 65), (2, 66), (2, 67), (0, 68), (0, 69), (0, 70), (0, 71), (0, 72), (0, 73), (0, 74), (0, 75), (0, 76), (0, 77), (0, 78), (0, 79), (0, 80), (0, 81), (0, 82), (4, 83), (0, 84), (1, 85), (0, 86), (0, 87), (0, 88), (0, 89), (0, 90), (0, 91), (0, 92), (0, 93), (0, 94), (0, 95), (2, 96), (0, 97), (0, 98), (0, 99), (0, 100), (3, 101), (2, 102), (2, 103), (0, 104), (0, 105), (3, 106), (3, 107), (0, 108), (4, 109), (5, 110), (0, 111), (4, 112), (0, 113), (4, 114), (0, 115), (4, 116), (0, 117), (0, 118), (0, 119), (0, 120), (5, 121), (2, 122), (2, 123), (0, 124), (0, 125), (0, 126), (4, 127), (0, 128), (0, 129), (0, 130), (0, 131), (0, 132), (0, 133), (0, 134), (0, 135), (2, 136), (4, 137), (0, 138), (0, 139), (0, 140), (2, 141), (2, 142), (5, 143), (0, 144), (0, 145), (4, 146), (5, 147), (0, 148), (0, 149), (0, 150), (0, 151), (0, 152), (0, 153), (0, 154), (0, 155), (0, 156), (3, 157), (0, 158), (0, 159), (0, 160), (5, 161), (1, 162), (0, 163), (5, 164), (0, 165), (5, 166), (0, 167), (0, 168), (0, 169), (0, 170), (0, 171), (0, 172), (0, 173), (0, 174), (0, 175), (4, 176), (0, 177), (4, 178), (0, 179), (5, 180), (5, 181), (0, 182), (0, 183), (3, 184), (5, 185), (5, 186), (0, 187), (0, 188), (0, 189), (0, 190), (0, 191), (0, 192), (0, 193), (0, 194), (0, 195), (0, 196), (0, 197), (0, 198), (0, 199), (2, 200), (5, 201), (0, 202), (0, 203), (0, 204), (4, 205), (0, 206), (0, 207), (0, 208), (0, 209), (0, 210), (0, 211), (0, 212), (0, 213), (0, 214), (0, 215), (4, 216), (0, 217), (0, 218), (0, 219), (5, 220), (3, 221), (2, 222), (0, 223), (5, 224), (4, 225), (4, 226), (0, 227), (0, 228), (0, 229), (0, 230), (0, 231), (4, 232), (4, 233), (0, 234), (3, 235), (0, 236), (0, 237), (0, 238), (0, 239), (3, 240), (5, 241), (1, 242), (0, 243), (4, 244), (0, 245), (5, 246), (0, 247), (4, 248), (0, 249), (0, 250), (4, 251), (4, 252), (3, 253), (0, 254), (0, 255), (0, 256), (0, 257), (0, 258), (0, 259), (0, 260), (5, 261), (5, 262), (2, 263), (0, 264), (0, 265), (3, 266), (2, 267), (0, 268), (0, 269), (3, 270), (5, 271), (2, 272), (0, 273), (0, 274), (0, 275), (0, 276), (0, 277), (0, 278), (0, 279), (4, 280), (4, 281), (2, 282), (1, 283), (0, 284), (0, 285), (3, 286), (2, 287), (0, 288), (0, 289), (5, 290), (2, 291), (2, 292), (0, 293), (0, 294), (0, 295), (0, 296), (0, 297), (0, 298), (0, 299), (0, 300), (0, 301), (4, 302), (4, 303), (1, 304), (1, 305), (0, 306), (0, 307), (0, 308), (0, 309), (4, 310), (2, 311), (3, 312), (0, 313), (0, 314), (0, 315), (1, 316), (0, 317), (0, 318), (0, 319), (0, 320), (0, 321), (0, 322), (0, 323), (1, 324), (2, 325), (2, 326), (2, 327), (0, 328), (0, 329), (0, 330), (4, 331), (0, 332), (2, 333), (2, 334), (0, 335), (0, 336), (0, 337), (0, 338), (0, 339), (0, 340), (0, 341), (0, 342), (0, 343), (0, 344), (0, 345), (0, 346), (2, 347), (0, 348), (0, 349), (0, 350), (0, 351), (0, 352), (0, 353), (0, 354), (0, 355), (0, 356), (0, 357), (0, 358), (0, 359), (0, 360), (0, 361), (0, 362), (0, 363), (0, 364), (0, 365), (0, 366), (0, 367), (0, 368), (0, 369), (0, 370), (0, 371), (0, 372), (0, 373), (0, 374), (0, 375), (0, 376), (0, 377), (0, 378), (0, 379), (0, 380), (0, 381), (0, 382), (0, 383), (0, 384), (0, 385), (0, 386), (0, 387), (0, 388), (0, 389), (0, 390), (0, 391), (0, 392), (0, 393), (0, 394), (0, 395), (0, 396), (0, 397), (0, 398), (0, 399)]
```

In this we have the image number and the block number. Now I want to pick block 0 from image 0 and put in empty image and so on. I hope this clears what is the expected output.

Answer (score 1):

So, here's my approach to your problem. I rewrote parts of your code to get rid of all the lists, and solely working on NumPy arrays. Therefore, I store all images in a 4D array, and store all calculated "block means" in a 3D array. Finally, I use the found `image_number` array to generate some kind of "index array" by using OpenCV's [`resize`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#ga47a974309e9102f5f08231edc7e7529d) method with [`INTER_AREA`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#ga5bb5a1fea74ea38e1a5445ca803ff121) interpolation flag (*"resampling using pixel area relation"*). In doing so, the generation of your final image can be done very easily using NumPy's [boolean array indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing).

Let's have a look at the following code:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Read images in one single 4D array; resize to [200, 200]
nImages = 3
images = np.zeros((200, 200, 3, nImages), np.uint8)
images[:, :, :, 0] = cv2.resize(cv2.imread('U2Gmz.png', cv2.IMREAD_COLOR), (200, 200))
images[:, :, :, 1] = cv2.resize(cv2.imread('OZxf3.png', cv2.IMREAD_COLOR), (200, 200))
images[:, :, :, 2] = cv2.resize(cv2.imread('aISEB.png', cv2.IMREAD_COLOR), (200, 200))

# Calculate block means and store in one single 3D array
means = np.zeros((20, 20, nImages), np.uint8)
for im in range(nImages):
    arr = np.split(images[:, :, :, im], 20)
    arr = np.array([np.split(x, 20, 1) for x in arr])
    means[:, :, im] = np.reshape([arr[i][j].mean() for i in range(20) for j in range(20)], (20, 20))

# Determine block mean maximum over all images
result = np.max(means, axis=2)

# Determine index of block mean maximum over all images
image_number = np.argmax(means, axis=2)
print(image_number)

# Resize index array with "resampling using pixel area relation" to final image size
image_number_idx = cv2.resize(np.uint8(image_number), (200, 200), interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA)

# Generate final image by boolean array indexing
final = np.zeros((200, 200, 3), np.uint8)
for im in range(nImages):
    idx = image_number_idx == im
    final[idx, :] = images[idx, :, im]

# Show images
cv2.imshow('image1', images[:, :, :, 0])
cv2.imshow('image2', images[:, :, :, 1])
cv2.imshow('image3', images[:, :, :, 2])
cv2.imshow('final', final)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

These are the used images:

[image: Input 1]

[image: Input 2]

[image: Input 3]

The `image_number` output gives this:

```
[[0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0]
 [1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1]
 [0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 1 1 1 2 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 1 0 0 2 2 2 0 0 0 1 1 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 2 2 2 1 0 2 2 2 2 0 0 0 1 1 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 2 2 2 0 0 0 0 2 2 2 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 2 2 2 2 0 0 0 0 2 2 2 2 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 2 0 2 2 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [1 1 0 0 0 2 2 0 0 2 2 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [1 1 0 0 2 2 2 0 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 2 0 2 1]
 [1 0 0 0 0 2 2 2 2 0 2 2 2 2 2 2 0 1 1 1]
 [1 1 1 0 0 2 2 2 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 0 0 1 1 0]
 [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0]
 [1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1]]
```

And, the final image looks like this:

[image: Output]

I hope, I understood your question correctly, and this is what you wanted to achieve.

My assumption is, that all input images have the same image dimensions, `(200, 200)` here. Otherwise, I couldn't think of a way to manage potentially varying block sizes, if just the "grid", `(20, 20)` here, is fixed.

Hope that helps!

**EDIT:** To read all `jpg` files from the given folder, you might use:

```py
files = glob.glob('resized/*.jpg')

# Read images in one single 4D array; resize to [200, 200]
nImages = len(files)
images = np.zeros((200, 200, 3, nImages), np.uint8)
for im in range(nImages):
    images[:, :, :, im] = cv2.resize(cv2.imread(files[im], cv2.IMREAD_COLOR), (200, 200))
```

Comment: Thank you so much @HansHirse for taking the time out to produce this result. I just have one small question that instead of reading the image files one by one can't we read them using glob?

Comment: @ChristinaEvans I added some code at the end of my answer regarding this point. Please see, if that works for you.

Comment: you are AWESOME!!! Worked like a charm. Been stuck at it for quite a long time and you saved the day. Thankyou so much.

Comment: @ChristinaEvans Please upvote any answers you find useful.

Comment: @kkuilla I cannot upvote yet. I don't have the privilege yet.

Answer (score 0):

I consider you wonder to know how to merge two or more images. In python, when you load an image using opencv, it is stored in numpy arrays. So it is easy using numpy. Below is an example to merge two images.
Firstly, load two images:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

img1 = cv2.imread('pic1.png')
img2 = cv2.imread('pic2.png')

cv2.imshow('img1', img1)
cv2.imshow('img2', img2)
```

the two images are like:

[image]  [image]

Then to merge those two imgs:

```py
# get the height and width of those pictures
h1, w1 = img1.shape[:2]
h2, w2 = img2.shape[:2]

# define the height and width of the merged pictures
h, w = max(h1, h2), w1 + w2
img = np.zeros((h, w, 3), np.uint8)

# paste each img to the right place
img[0:h1, 0:w1] = img1
img[0:h2, w1:] = img2

cv2.imshow('img', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

the result would be like:

[image]

Comment: I'll make changes to my post to clarify my question.

Comment: Sorry to misunderstood you, but I hope this answer can give you some inspiration. Just treat images as arrays, you can change the content as you want.