# Merge blocks of images to produce new image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, python-imaging-library

Hi is there a way of merging specific blocks from multiple images of same size(say 100x100) and putting them together in a new image. To be more specific, consider I have a set of images which have been divided into blocks of same size(say 10x10). Now I want to access block 1 from image 1 and block 2 from image 2, block 3 from image 1, block 4 from image 5 and so on till I finish all 100 blocks. Is there a way to do so using python.

```
img_1 = [cv2.imread(file,0) for file in glob.glob("trial_images/*.jpg")]
Y=[]
for img in img_1:
    arr_new = np.asarray(img)
    arr_new = np.split(arr_new, 10)
    arr_new = np.array([np.split(x, 10, 1) for x in arr_new])
    matrix1= [arr_new[i][j] for i in range(10) for j in range(10)]
    Y.append(matrix1)
```

Till now I have managed to divide the images into blocks and I have the values of each block. Now I am stuck on how to get block from original images and draw them onto a new image file.

Comment: What have you attempted so far?

Comment: yes, it is possible. But you should describe details and show your code.

Comment: [Same exercise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58369483)?

Comment: @HansHirse looks like it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Combine blocks of different images and produce a new image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58369483/combine-blocks-of-different-images-and-produce-a-new-image) @Newbie I posted an answer to the before-mentioned question. Maybe have a look, if that (also) works for you.

Comment: Thanks HansHirse. I just need to make some changes in that code. But I really appreciate your effort.

Answer (score 0):

Use the cv2 addWeighted function ([link](http://result%20=%20cv2.addWeighted(image,%201,%20newwarp,%200.3,%200))) to merge the images. Basically you are running a weighted sum over the matrics such that ***AxImage1 + BxImage2 = NewImage***. Where A and B are constants and Image**N** is your image.

Comment: @RodrigoLozo Thanks for your effort but the link is not working

Comment: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/03/07/transparent-overlays-with-opencv/

Comment: @RodrigoLozo it is used for blending two images together. But in my case I want blocks from different images. For instance, block1 from image 1, block2 from image 2, block3 from image 3, block4 from image1 and so on. Can addWeighted function be used for that purpose.

Comment: Of course, just insert the matrices to the function respectively.