# Merge blocks of images and display image numbers

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, python-imaging-library

Hi I have started image processing in which I am using a number of images. For each image I have found the edges using canny. Each image is of same dimension 500x500. Now I have to divide these images into blocks and find the mean value of the pixels in each block.Then compare each block of the images to find the maximum among all the images. At the end I want to produce the final images with blocks from all the images with a functionality of hovering over the blocks. On hovering over the final images on a particular block, it should show the image number and the intensity of information in that block. I have managed to find the edges and then I read those edge detected images to divide them into blocks. I want to know how to construct a new images using these blocks with the hovering functionality.

```
def auto_canny(image, sigma=0.33):
    # Compute the median of the single channel pixel intensities
    v = np.median(image)

    # Apply automatic Canny edge detection using the computed median
    lower = int(max(0, (1.0 - sigma) * v))
    upper = int(min(255, (1.0 + sigma) * v))
    return cv2.Canny(image, lower, upper)

# Read in each image and convert to grayscale
images = [cv2.imread(file,0) for file in glob.glob("images/*.jpg")]

# Iterate through each image, perform edge detection, and save image
number = 0
for image in images:
    canny = auto_canny(image)
    cv2.imwrite('edges_canny/canny_{}.jpg'.format(number), canny)
    number += 1


num = 0
for image_file_name in os.listdir('edges_canny/'):
     im = Image.open('edges_canny/'+image_file_name)
     new_width  = 500
     new_height = 500
     im = im.resize((new_width, new_height), Image.ANTIALIAS)
     im.save('downsize/canny_{}'.format(num) + '.jpg')
     num +=1


img = [cv2.imread(file,0) for file in glob.glob("downsize/*.jpg")]
Block=[]
for im in img:
    arr = np.asarray(im)
    arr = np.split(arr, 50)
    arr = np.array([np.split(x, 50, 1) for x in arr])
    block= [arr[i][j].median() for i in range(50) for j in range(50)]
    Block.append(block)

max_X = list(zip(*Block))
result = [max(i) for i in max_X]
print(result)
```

Now I am stuck. I could build this much using codes from several posts. Now can someone help me to produce the image with image number on the final image.

Comment: [Do you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58369483)
[people all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58370106)
[attend the](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58404164)
[same class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58387181)? Your actual question is exactly the same as [Christina's second one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58404164).

Comment: @HansHirse I have no idea who the first guy is but  yes Christina is a colleague of mine.

Comment: You learn most by figuring out yourself. @HansHirse solved the blocks, for the hovering I'll give you a pointer. Look into [setMouseCallback()](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.5/d7/dfc/group__highgui.html#ga89e7806b0a616f6f1d502bd8c183ad3e). On move, get the x/y coordinate to determine the source image.